# Why is my json data not being INSERTed into mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, webhooks

I created a PHP handler to receive a JSON payload from a POST request and then insert it into a database in phpMyAdmin. I'm not sure why this is not working.

JSON:

```
payload = {  
    "version":"1.0",
    "event":"video_recorded",
    "data":{
        "videoName":"vs1457013120534_862",
        "audioCodec":"NellyMoser ASAO",
        "videoCodec":"H.264",
        "type":"FLV",
        "orientation":"landscape",
        "id":"0",
        "dateTime":"2016-03-03 15:51:44",
        "timeZone":"Europe/Bucharest",
        "payload":"111.111.111.11",
        "httpReferer":"http://site_from_where_video_was_recorded.com"
    }
}
```

The PHP code I got from a tutorial online. The tutorial was from 2017 so I'm assuming everything is up to date, but yet it still does not work:

```
<?php

/* db variables */

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'name_db';
$dbuser = 'user_db';
$dbpass = 'pass_db';

/* grab the json */

$data = $_POST['payload'];

/* put json into php associative array */

$data_array = json_decode($data);

/* store in PHP variables */

$ip_address = $data_array['data']['payload'];
$vid_name = $data_array['data']['videoName'];
$date_time = $data_array['data']['dateTime'];
$time_zone = $data_array['data']['timeZone'];

/* connect to mysql db */

$con = mysql_connect($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbhost) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

/* select the specific db */

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

/* insert the values into the db */

$sql = "INSERT INTO ip_and_videos(IpAddress, VideoName, DateTime, Timezone) VALUES('$ip_address','$vid_name','$date_time','$time_zone')";

if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

I have the primary key set to an int and have it on auto increment. If I understand correctly I don't need to insert anything into that column because it will assign a number each time. Or do I still need to pass it when I INSERT the other variables?

Comment: stop using mysql Extensions. Your code is open for sql Injection.

Comment: okay I will look into it. Any idea why its not working as it is?

Comment: No. You don't have to pass because primary key is auto increment. Update your question with your error. And start error_reporting(E_ALL) at the starting of your code so if there is any other errors occurs we can figure it out also.

Comment: I honestly don't even know how to trouble shoot this, new to php. Would the error show in the dev tools console on chrome?

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer : please check answer and let us know... Beware also your query, let it breath as you lack some spaces between parts of it -> ip_and_videos( and VALUES(

Comment: Sorry I'm getting Aptana set up so I can debug it. Ive been doing everything with FileZilla and that doesn't help much. Give me a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the array part, you get correct answer. So, your code is not bad, but you should check all errors (as stated by Bhavin in comment). And I'm retty sure you have a typo -> $vid_name = $data_array['data']['videName']; is **NOT** like $vid_name = $data_array['data']['vide**o**Name']; Thereforer, error_reporting will be very helpful, and after that, check the query if other errors (prepared statements ^^)

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$payload = '{  
          "version":"1.0",
          "event":"video_recorded",
          "data": {
              "videoName":"vs1457013120534_862",
              "audioCodec":"NellyMoser ASAO",
              "videoCodec":"H.264",
              "type":"FLV",
              "orientation":"landscape",
              "id":"0",
              "dateTime":"2016-03-03 15:51:44",
              "timeZone":"Europe/Bucharest",
              "payload":"111.111.111.11",
                "httpReferer":"http://site_from_where_video_was_recorded.com"
          }
      }';

$data_array = json_decode($payload, true);

/* store in PHP variables */

$ip_address = $data_array['data']['payload'];
$vid_name = $data_array['data']['videoName'];
$date_time = $data_array['data']['dateTime'];
$time_zone = $data_array['data']['timeZone'];

echo"[ $ip_address / $vid_name / $date_time / $time_zone ]";

// EDIT : added query

include"config.inc.php";

// connect to DB
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$mdp", "$db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Error connecting : " . mysqli_connect_error($mysqli); }

$query = " INSERT INTO ip_and_videos (`IpAddress`, `VideoName`, `DateTime`, `Timezone`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

print_r($stmt->error_list);

$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $ip_address, $vid_name, $date_time, $time_zone );

if (!$stmt->execute()) { echo $stmt->error; } else { echo"true"; }

?>
```

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer  : did you try it and are they any errors thrown with my code when you run it ? if yes, what are they ? EDIT : **just** the code, nothing else on the page but your parameters for DB please

Comment: I'm still trying to figure that part out. I downloaded Aptana and set up the ftp. Now it keeps opening up Firefox when I try to run the code and won't even show an echo.

Comment: I'm getting this when I go to the url of my handler ` Column 'IpAddress' cannot be null`

Comment: mysql error tells you your 'IpAddress' column need some data to be inserted -> does the line echo"[ $ip_address / $vid_name / $date_time / $time_zone ]"; show all 4 $vars ? any empty ? (NOTE: running this script in my own DB online worked like a charm)

Comment: No I'm not even getting the variables for some reason. I have the json saved in a payload variable and everything. `hello[ / / / ]Array ( ) Column 'IpAddress' cannot be null`

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer : put a print_r($_POST); et see what error it throws, because the problem comes from here

Comment: Oh my gosh you are a godsend I must of butchered my code, when I copy paste from yours it started working again. Now to test with the webhook vice the hard-coded json.

Comment: Good Sir, you are my saving grace!

Comment: thanks (and for the UV + accepted answer too ^^) and good code in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you had the same issue but this does not work for me...

```
$vid_name = $data_array['data']['videName'];
```

I had to use

```
$vid_name = $data_array->data->videoName;
```

Can't use stdClass as an array.

Comment: where did you get payload from? should I use $data_array?

Comment: Sorry, I used payload in the example I worked out on my machine... I made the edit.

Comment: Hmm, still getting `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0002 seconds.)` when I look at the db. The JSON is going to my handler so that has to be the issue

Comment: also mysql_select_db is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Should be better this way

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* db variables */

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'name_db';
$dbuser = 'user_db';
$dbpass = 'pass_db';

/* grab the json */

$data = $_POST['payload'];

/* put json into php associative array */

$alldata = json_decode($data,true);
print_r($alldata);

/* connect to mysql db */

$con = mysql_connect($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbhost) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

/* select the specific db */

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

/* insert the values into the db */
foreach($alldata as $data_array) {

$ip_address = $data_array['data']['payload'];
$vid_name = $data_array['data']['videoName'];
$date_time = $data_array['data']['dateTime'];
$time_zone = $data_array['data']['timeZone'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO ip_and_videos(IpAddress, VideoName, DateTime, Timezone) VALUES('".$ip_address."','".$vid_name."','".$date_time."','".$time_zone."')";
mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";
}

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: still nothing in the db

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer to understand what is going on, I updated code, it should throw some error

Comment: so I'm getting a ` Column 'IpAddress' cannot be null` error on OldPadawans code below. ill give this one a shot.

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer also videName should be fixed as videoName